# Is there a way to target images in a directory based on names?

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, image

I am redesigning a site that is built using WordPress. I have updated the theme, added customization, etc - but, there are tons of pages for each publication volume which have a cover image, all of which have no class or id added. I'm not sure how they were imported from the static old static version of the site, and I have no way on contacting the previous developers.

The images all begin with "Vol-" in the image name, so is there a way to target these images in order to added a class and resize them? I'd like to apply a class to these specifically instead of going through literally hundreds of pages to do so. Is this possible with jQuery?

One caveat, if it matters: they are contained within a table, with a figure image beside it.

Example: http://jmpee.org/whitepapers/current-issue-2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can target such image with selector "Attribute SRC begins with Vol-": `img[src^="Vol-"]`. The styling can be done in pure CSS, e.g.

```
img[src^="Vol-"] {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border:solid 1px blue
}
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/KCnEg/**

If you prefer to use jQuery, same selector can be used as jQuery selector. Note that if actual attribute does not begin with "Vol-", for example it's something like `<img src="http://mysite/folder/vol-15.png" />` you can target selector "Attribute SRC contains Vol-": `img[src*="Vol-"]`

Comment: Wow, really that simple, huh? Thanks, Yuriy. It's funny how you can miss out on the simplest of techniques sometimes. This saves me a lot of headache. That last bit is even more reassuring. It's possible some might not begin exactly with "Vol-" but contain the word "cover" within the name, so there's another way to target them.